# Where can I find netbeans html code templates?

Tags: download, html, netbeans, templates, code

In Netbeans 7.1 there are no html code templates included on install.

Where can I find some basic html templates to download?

Answer (score 1):

There should be.

Go to > Tools > Templates

Look inside the "Other" folder, there should be 2 HTML templates: "HTML file" & "XHTML FIle".

HTML FIle

```
<#assign licenseFirst = "<!--">
<#assign licensePrefix = "">
<#assign licenseLast = "-->">
<#include "../Licenses/license-${project.license}.txt">
${doctype}
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=${encoding}">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>TODO write content</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

XHTML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="${encoding}"?>
<#assign licenseFirst = "<!--">
<#assign licensePrefix = "">
<#assign licenseLast = "-->">
<#include "../Licenses/license-${project.license}.txt">
${doctype}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: now there is no `Tools > Templates` option